# PHP/MYSQL codeigniter live server issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi guys I would really appreciate if you can help me with this issue I am having. Basically what I am trying to do is to export data from mysql into a file using `into file` function. It works on local host but not on live server and I think it is something to do with the server path but cannot figure out a solution for it. Below is the code.

```
$path = "../etrade_files/Exports/Other/product_media_links.csv";
$enclosed_by = '"';

$sql = "(SELECT 'Product ID','Manufacturer','Part No','Model','URL','Image Name')
UNION
(SELECT product_id,manufacturer,part_no,model,url,image_name
FROM etrade_product_media_links
INTO OUTFILE '$path'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '$enclosed_by'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n')";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

`etade_file` is in website's root directory.

Thank you.

Comment: What errors do you get ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors script runs from start to finish as expected but it don't export the file.

Comment: Are you sure, have you got error_reporting enabled ? Put error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1); at the top of your script.

Comment: public function __construct()
    {parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('other_model');
   ini_set('memory_limit', '3000M');
   set_time_limit(0);
   error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   ini_set('display_errors',1); 
  }

Comment: I have got it on but not giving me any errors which is why I am a but confused myself.

Comment: var_dump(is_file($path)); try this to see if path pointing to the .csv file

Comment: It gave me bool(false).

Comment: So it's a wrong path.No .csv file at that path.

Comment: But the directory structure in the path does exists in the website's root directory which is why I dont get what's wrong. I think there might be a different way of working with paths on live server

Comment: Have you tried $path = "etrade_files/Exports/Other/product_media_links.csv"; like from my answer?

Comment: Also make sure that there is no some typo, like etade_file vs etrade_file.

Comment: I absolutely made sure everything is correct still dont work been trying to fix it for days now.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you should do something like this :

```
$path = "etrade_files/Exports/Other/product_media_links.csv";
$enclosed_by = '"';

$sql = "(SELECT 'Product ID','Manufacturer','Part No','Model','URL','Image Name')
UNION
(SELECT product_id,manufacturer,part_no,model,url,image_name
FROM etrade_product_media_links
INTO OUTFILE '$path'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '$enclosed_by'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n')";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

But first check where you have uploaded .csv file.

Comment: my base url is set to 'http://domain.com/etrade/'. Within etrade directory which is my web root directory there is etrade_files. I absolutely made sure everything is correct just dont understand what the problem is.

Comment: Well I don't know. Try using etrade/etrade_files/Exports/Other/product_media_links.csv or /etrade/etrade_files/Exports/Other/product_media_links.csv for $path. Good luck!